# How to refresh textview based on user input? Multi-threading Issue

Tags: android, multithreading, textview

I am checking a value: `borrow[0]`, based on which i need to refresh by `TextView` called `message`. all this is happening inside a `method()` which is called from `button.setOnClickListener` event  in `onCreateView()` of my fragment.

```
if (borrow[0]) {
    Log.i("inside borrow", borrow[0] +"");
    message.setText("You have successfully borrowed the book. Due date is" + dueDate[0].substring(0, Math.min(dueDate[0].length(), 10)));
}
if (!borrow[0]){
    Log.i("inside borrow", borrow[0] +"");
    message.setText("This book is already borrowed by you.");
}
```

This button can be clicked many times.

I understand from other forums that I need to refresh it in different lifecycle method. Can anyone advise which method I can use? coz my `borrow[0]` is only accessible in my `method()`, so need to find out a way - where to store so that can access it from "that lifecycle method". appreciate a sample code as I am not much familiar with lifecycle methods. Many thanks in advance.

Let me paste my entire method code:

```
public void borrowItem(String patronId, final String itemId) {
        final int DEFAULT_TIMEOUT = 200000 * 1000000000;
        String str;
//        final boolean[] borrow = new boolean[1];
//        final String[] dueDate = new String[1];

        AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
        client.setTimeout(DEFAULT_TIMEOUT);
        progress.setMessage("Please Wait...");
        progress.setIndeterminate(false);
        progress.setCancelable(false);

        progress.show();

//        final String[] names = new String[4];
        final CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);

        Thread t = new Thread() {

            public void run() {
                Looper.prepare(); //For Preparing Message Pool for the child Thread
                HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(client.getParams(), 100000000); //Timeout Limit
                HttpResponse response;

                try {

                    HttpPost post = new HttpPost("http://...........");

                    JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
                    try {
                        json.put("itemID", itemId);
                        json.put("userID", sharedpreferences.getString("PatronID", null));
                        json.put("sessionID", sharedpreferences.getString("PatronIdKey", null));
                        Log.i("CVPL --> sessionid", sharedpreferences.getString("PatronIdKey", null));

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    StringEntity se = new StringEntity(json.toString());
                    Log.i("CVPL --> json", json.toString());

                    se.setContentType(new BasicHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json"));
                    post.setEntity(se);
                    response = client.execute(post);
//                    Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "XML File:" + response , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                            /*Checking response */
                    if (response != null) {

                        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                        String result = EntityUtils.toString(entity);

//                        Log.i("CVPL - AccFrag", result);

                        progress.dismiss();

                        final CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);
                        final String[] names = new String[4];
                        JSONArray mArray, mArray1, mArray2;
//                        int totalCount=0;
//                        int avail=0;
                        String value, title, publisher;

                        try {
                            JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(result);

                            //Results
                            if (obj.getJSONObject("Results") != null) {
                                JSONObject obj1 = obj.getJSONObject("Results");

                                //LookupTitleInfoResponse
                                if (obj1.getJSONObject("CheckoutResponse") != null) {
                                    JSONObject obj2 = obj1.getJSONObject("CheckoutResponse");
//                                    Log.i("obj2.getString(dueDate)", obj2.getString("dueDate"));

                                    //TitleInfo
                                    if (!obj2.getString("dueDate").equals("null")) {
                                        JSONObject obj3 = obj2.getJSONObject("dueDate");

                                        value = obj3.getString("value");
//                                    if(value != null)

                                        Log.i("due date:", value.substring(0, Math.min(value.length(), 10)));
//                                                Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "Due Date:" + value , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
//                                                    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
//                                                    builder.setMessage("You have successfully borrowed the book. Due date is" + value).create().show();
                                        borrow[0] = true;
                                        dueDate[0] = value;
                                        Log.i("borrow", borrow[0] + "");

                                    } else {
//                                        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
//                                        builder.setMessage("This book is already borrowed by you.").create().show();

                                        borrow[0] = false;
                                        Log.i("borrow", borrow[0] + "");

                                    }

                                }
                            }
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

//                        replaceFragment(result);

                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }

        };

        t.start();


        Log.i("borrow after thread", borrow[0] + "");
        if (borrow[0]) {
            Log.i("inside borrow", borrow[0] +"");
            message.setText("You have successfully borrowed the book. Due date is" + dueDate[0].substring(0, Math.min(dueDate[0].length(), 10)));
        }
        if (!borrow[0]){
            Log.i("inside borrow", borrow[0] +"");
            message.setText("This book is already borrowed by you.");
        }
    }
```

MY button event:

```
  borrowBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (v.getId() == R.id.checkout_button) {

                    if (first_time_check()== true) {
//                        getAccInfo(sharedpreferences.getString("PatronIdKey", null), getArguments().getString("barcode"));
                        borrowItem(sharedpreferences.getString("PatronIdKey", null), getArguments().getString("barcode"));

                        Log.i("after borrow", borrow[0] + "");
                        if (borrow[0]) {
                            Log.i("inside borrow", borrow[0] +"");
                            message.setText("You have successfully borrowed the book. Due date is: " + dueDate[0].substring(0, Math.min(dueDate[0].length(), 10)));
                        }
                        if (!borrow[0]){
                            Log.i("inside borrow", borrow[0] +"");
                            message.setText("This book is already borrowed by you.");
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        });
```

My variable declaration:

```
public class Checkout extends Fragment {
    final boolean[] borrow = new boolean[1];
    final String[] dueDate = new String[1];
```

Not sure after start thread, why remaining code is not called? I mostly see - "This book is already borrowed by you." message as the result even when borrow[0] = true. Not sure if its due to thread?

Comment: Why don't you declare `borrow` variable as a member of class ?

Comment: yes, I can do that. but which lifecycle method will refresh the textview?

Comment: I didn't get your question clearly, What are you trying to do actually ? As I guess you are setting something to TextView on button clicked am I right ?

Comment: i dont think there is need to refresh.. setting value will do it.. just update scope of your variable

Comment: @virendrao, change the scope of variable too but same issue.

Comment: added entire code. hope it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recall your method in certain period of time, There is no any magical Lifecycle event to asynchronously refresh your `TextViews`

```
 CountDownTimer t = new CountDownTimer(MAX_VALUE , 10000) {

        // This is called every 10 seconds interval.
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            refreshViews();
        }

        public void onFinish() {       
            start();
        }
     }.start();

public void refreshViews(){
                if (first_time_check()== true) {
                    borrowItem(sharedpreferences.getString("PatronIdKey", null), getArguments().getString("barcode"));

                    Log.i("after borrow", borrow[0] + "");
                    if (borrow[0]) {
                        Log.i("inside borrow", borrow[0] +"");
                        message.setText("You have successfully borrowed the book. Due date is: " + dueDate[0].substring(0, Math.min(dueDate[0].length(), 10)));
                    }
                    if (!borrow[0]){
                        Log.i("inside borrow", borrow[0] +"");
                        message.setText("This book is already borrowed by you.");
                    }    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare the `TextView` as a public variable in your `Fragment` class. Then get the view reference of the `TextView` inside `onCreateView` lifecycle method. Now the `TextView` can be easily accessed from the `method()` function you've got there. Here's an example code that might help you.

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment {

  private TextView message;

  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.your_fragment_layout, container, false);
    message = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.message);

    // Here's your button.setOnClickListener
  }

  private void method() {
    if (borrow[0]) {
      Log.i("inside borrow", borrow[0] +"");
      message.setText("You have successfully borrowed the book. Due date is" + dueDate[0].substring(0, Math.min(dueDate[0].length(), 10)));

    } else {
      Log.i("inside borrow", borrow[0] +"");
      message.setText("This book is already borrowed by you.");
    }
  }
}
```

Check if your thread is returning null here.

```
obj1.getJSONObject("CheckoutResponse")
```

Comment: This is exactly what I am doing, I am calling method() on button click listener. I also declared borrow[0] as class variable, but refreshing is a problem.

Comment: This works, but there is some gap - first wrong msg displays and after a while right msg. Is it possible to shorten the gap? Also can you explain the reason why it was happening. Thanks for your solution.

Comment: Glad to know that helped. Its the thread which is responsible for this time gap. You should handle the Thread in a smarted way. In android we use AsyncTask for this type of tasks. As you've already accepted an answer, I think you've solved your problem already.

Comment: I accepted the answer as it resolved my original issue. Just wanted to know if its possible to shorten the gap (improve performance of solution)?